# Enforce brace position for type annotation

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

There is a plethora of rules for code style, e.g. `brace-style`, `comma-dangle`, `object-curly-spacing`, `object-property-newline`, `object-curly-newline` (and the array counterparts). None of them seem to prevent misplaced brackets in typescript annotations, like

```
let a: [number, string,
];
let b: {p: number,
  s: string, };
```

For standard javascript objects/arrays, i use the following, which should in a sense also apply:

```
"object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always", { "objectsInObjects": true, "arraysInObjects": true }],
"array-bracket-spacing": "error",
"object-property-newline": ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true }],
"array-element-newline": ["error", "consistent"],
"object-curly-newline": ["error", { "multiline": true }],
"array-bracket-newline": "error",
```

There also seem to not be any `@typescript-eslint` extensions, which incorporate this behavior for type annotations. I've found e.g. `@typescript-eslint/brace-style`, but it doesn't work for definitions like above.

Did i just overlook the rule i need (there are really a lot afterall), or is this not possible with the standard rules? How can i achieve consistent style here?

Comment: Not an answer, but the advice would be to turn off all coding style linting rules and just switch install prettier to keep consistency.

Comment: Thanks, it's an option, but i am typically very mad, when anything auto-formats my code. I write what i write, and it's no program's right to change anything. Passively showing me, when i am inconsistent, is however desired. Then i either fix it, push for an eslint rule change, or just add a `// eslint-disable` in front.

Comment: I would echo what Shanon Jackson said - letting go and using prettier is a much better solution than trying to customise every single lint rule to an exact code style. Lint rules are very much fallible, and often do not enforce certain cases, leading to inconsistency in your codebase. Speaking as an ESLint plugin maintainer - they're also ***VERY*** hard to write and maintain - which is why ESLint core is no longer doing them - https://eslint.org/blog/2020/05/changes-to-rules-policies. All stylistic rules in typescript-eslint are solely community maintained.

Comment: Configuring an automatic code formatter would imho be more difficult. In ESLint, i set rules for situations, where i am certain, what the style should look like. For a formatter, i'd set exceptions, for when i am not sure. There are however considerably more exceptions than norms. The linting settings frequently allow multiple different stylings, because the situation may prefer one or the other, and there isn't an AI advanced enough to determine, which is better (yet). An automatic mechanism would also need a good 'undo', and easy exceptions. Prettier is opinionated, making it even worse.